# Mathematical formula to always center text along X and Y axis ffmpeg python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am trying to center a text horizontally and vertically with ffmpeg python but I can't seem to get it right. The mid point shifts depending on the amount of characters in the text.

How do I always center the text to the centre of the screen no matter the length of the text?

Here is my code.

```
v_width = 1080

v_height = 1633

def create_video():

    overlay1 = ffmpeg.input("sukuna.gif").filter("scale", 1080, -1, height = 1633 / 2)

    overlay2 = ffmpeg.input("akaza_long.mp4").filter("scale", 1080, -1, height = 1633 / 2 )

    (

    ffmpeg.input('letsgo.mp4')

    .overlay(overlay1)

    .overlay(overlay2, x = 0, y = v_height / 2)

    .drawtext(textfile = "char_names.txt", fontfile = "/storage/emulated/0/PyFiles/Helvetica-Bold.ttf", fontcolor = "yellow", bordercolor = "black", escape_text = True, start_number = 0, fontsize = "80", x = (v_width / 2) - 40, y = (v_height / 2) - 40, borderw = 4, line_spacing = 3)

    .output("newVideo.mp4")

    .run()

    )
```

The - 40 is for adding some extra padding to the text.

How do I go about this?

I want the below position always no matter how big or amount of characters in the text.
[Centred text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKLm7.jpg)

Already tried adding a couple of offset to the text but once the text gets longer, it loses its alignment.

Comment: See the 3rd example at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-71

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` and `y` variables are not just integers. There are supposed to be string containing an expression.

And one valid "vocabulary" of this expression is `tw`, which is the width of the text.

So, in your case, you could

```py
    .drawtext(textfile = "char_names.txt", fontfile = "/storage/emulated/0/PyFiles/Helvetica-Bold.ttf", fontcolor = "yellow", bordercolor = "black", escape_text = True, start_number = 0, fontsize = "80", x = f'{v_width // 2} - tw/2', y = f'{v_height//2} - th/2', borderw = 4, line_spacing = 3)
```

Note that `W` and `H` are also valid vocabulary of those expressions. So you don't need those hard coded `v_width` and `v_height`. You can also, instead of expanding them in python (like I did with previous f-string, in which `{v_width//2}` is computed before passing the string to ffmpeg), let ffmpeg do the job, and therefore having something more adaptative and less hard coded.

```py
    .drawtext(textfile = "char_names.txt", fontfile = "/storage/emulated/0/PyFiles/Helvetica-Bold.ttf", fontcolor = "yellow", bordercolor = "black", escape_text = True, start_number = 0, fontsize = "80", x = 'W/2 - tw/2', y = 'H/2 - th/2', borderw = 4, line_spacing = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am literally crying. This problem has haunted me for days. I didn't know about these vocabulary where can I read more about them?

By the way, is there a vocab for center aligning the text. Something like "Sukuna Vs Akaza" gets right aligned instead of center aligned.
Thanks.